# ListItem onPress not finding key

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux, native-base

I'm using React Native with react-native-router-flux and native-base. I have created a SideMenu with native -base and navigate with  react-native-router-flux. The problem is that when i click to ListItem it does not navigate to the screen i want.

- const datas = [
  {
  name: 'Home',
  key: 'home',
  icon: 'home',
  bg: '#C5F442',

  },
  {
  name: 'Profile',
  key:'profile',
  icon: 'user-circle-o',
  bg: '#477EEA',
  types: '8',
  }`

  *

  ```
          onPress={() =>{Actions.data.key()}}> 

            <Icon active name={data.icon} style={styles.icon} />
            <Text style={styles.text}>{data.name}</Text>


        </ListItem>}
    />



                 The declaration of scene
                    <Scene key='profile'
                          component={Profile} 
                          title='Profile' 
                          hideNavBar={true} 
                          tabs={true} />
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want make this in that way:

```
Actions[data.key]({})
```

Comment: And if i may ask how can i close the NavDrawer when [data.key]({}) executed? I tried

          onPress={() => {  Actions[data.key]({}); Actions.refresh({key: 'drawer', open: value => !value });}} > 

but it just closes the NavDrawer

Comment: I'm using redux in my project so in Drawer I have open={this.props.global.drawerOpened} and i change that attribute via redux